# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

When I select the table row, nothing happens. It didn't go to ContentController and I can't find the `UILabel` that I declared on ContentController.h when I want to link it to `resultLabel`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ContentController *detailview = [[ContentController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentController" bundle:nil];    
    detailview.detailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailview animated:YES];     
    [detailview release];
}
```

ContentController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    resultLabel.text = self.detailString;
}
```

Comment: You need to check that have you define UITableViewDelegate to your file or attach table view delegate to your file owner.

Comment: Is your current view controller contains navigationController? Is you project navigation based?

Comment: I have attached table view delegate to the file owner.

Comment: I have tried contains navigationController and without navigationController, both are not working. It's a view based

Answer (score 15):

This may be because you don't have set your table view property to delegate & datasource by:

```
tableview.delegate=self;
tableview.datasource=self;
```

or set their property in xib is another option

Comment: I agree on this one, it seems the delegate has not been assigned

Answer (score 3):

### clickable == NO

Can be a state that in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
cell = [self tableCellWithHeight:height clickable:NO withArrowAccessory:NO];
```

`if clickable == NO` then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method will never called for that cell.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check is to make sure the prototype cells and their selection mode or selection style.

*Goto interface builder >>> utility windows on the right hand side >>> attributes inspector >>> Look for Selection drop down list.*

In the apple tutorial I was following, it asks you to set it to none, making it look like that the didSelect' delegate was not firing. Setting it the selection mode to none, effectively neutered this ability. I changed this to Single Selection and it all started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Check is control is coming inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath applying breakpoint. If not just check whether you have set the UITableView delegate or not.

Comment: how to set the UITableView delegate?

Comment: tablename.datasource = self; and if you work with xib then right click on table and map delegate an datasource to file owner

Comment: tableViewName.delegate = self and add UITableViewDelegate in .h file in @interface MoreRecent : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

in your ContentController.h

```
NSString *detailString;

@property (nonatomic, retain) detailString;
```

ContentController.m

```
@synthesize detailString;
```

And in your class where you have table view. set table view delegate & datasource to self (in xib to file owner).

Comment: Did That. But weird I can't find the detailString to connect at the .xib

Comment: add this in viewDidLoad : labelName.text = detailString;

Answer (score 0):

Here is an image of setting the datasource and delegate in interface builder for UITableview
which is necessary for the method below to fire on touch.

..

```
                - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
                {
                    return [self.myAlphabet count];
                }

                - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                {
                    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];    
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.myAlphabet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    return cell;
                }

                - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                {
                    //method for getting text (can be changed to push views)
                    NSString*mystring;
                    mystring = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
                    NSLog(@"%@",mystring);    
                }
```

[image: Setting datasource and delegate in interface builder]

Answer (score 0):

When creating cell (on cellForRowAtIndexPath) should notice to:

**userInteractionEnabled property** 
 Determine if cell can be selected (on click should -didSelectRowAtIndexPath will call).

```
if (!isClickable) {
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

**selectionStyle property:**
 Determine if selected backround view will show on click.

```
cell.selectionStyle = isClickable ? UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue : UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , i had some different scenario , i am having `HJManaged` Image in `UITableView` cell and `HJManaged` Image has its own tap method in its `delegate` , so when i tap on table view instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , delegate tap method of `HJManaged` Image getting called.

So what i found solution , i went back `UITableView` Cell , And unchecked User Interaction enabled property of `HJManaged` Image.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are implement this method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return NO;
}
```

it disable the cell selection

Answer (score 0):

This occurs may be you have not add your table view delegate and data source.Please ensure and add these two lines in your view did load methods

```
     tableview.delegate=self;
     tableview.datasource=self;
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation is I forgot to set **Delegate property** of the tableView. Maybe you should connect tableView delegate to current view controller.